# Mongodb assertion 28616 "Runner killed during find"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, error-handling, assertion

I am running a NodeJS script that connects to my Mongo Oplog to watch the deltas.  Periodically, I get the following Mongo error:

```
assertion 28616 Runner killed during find ns:local.oplog.rs query:{ orderby: { $natural: 1 }, $query: { ns: "Foo", ts: { $gt: Timestamp 1467969843000|2841 } } }
```

I have looked around in the documentation and such and have not found anything to direct me on how to resolve the issue, and avoid getting this error from time to time.  Anyone else out there seen this?

Comment: I knew MongoDB was killing people. Finally, some proof.

Comment: I have also seen this. I don't know where/why yet.

Comment: found any fix to this ?